# Invariant nontrivial subspace under every invertible linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional vector space of over a finite field $\mathbb F_p$, where $p$ is a prime number. Does there exist a non-trivial subspace $W$ of $V$ such that $W$ is $A$-invariant for every invertible linear transformation $A : V \to V$?

Can someone give me a note to this question? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a non-trivial subspace $W$ you can construct an invertible linear transformation $A$ for which $W$ is not an invariant subspace as follows: take a basis $b_1, \dots, b_k$ of $W$ and extend it to a basis $b_1,\dots b_n$ of $V$. Also, take a vector $b_1'$ that is not in $W$ and extend it to a basis $b_1', \dots, b_n'$ of $V$. Now the linear transformation defined by $b_i \mapsto b_i', i = 1, \dots n$ is invertible and sends $b_1 \in W$ to $b_1' \notin W$, so in particular $W$ is not invariant under it.

This works over any base field and for any (not necessarily finite) dimension.

Comment: Thank you very much!